# Variables in Batch FTP script

Tags: batch-file, ftp, ftp-client

In `C` you can use `%username%` as a `variable` for the current user's name for directory listings and such: `c:\documents and settings\%username%\`

Is there something like this for a batch script?
Using just `%username%` doesn't seem to help.

I wrote a script that accesses my FTP server so I can load files to the server.
I want my friends to be able to use this script, but I don't want to have to write several different scripts.
Here is what I have so far:

```
@echo off
@ftp -s:"%~f0" &GOTO: EOF
open FTP.server.com
user
pass
cd /home/ftp
bin
lcd "c:\documents and settings\%username%\my documents\FTP"
mput *txt
pause
bye
```

There's gotta be a way

Answer (score 1):

This can be done if you change the batch file so that it *creates* a script file every time the batch file runs. You can do this by using the `echo` command to write the script lines to script file, which you can then pass to the `ftp` command. The reason this works is that `echo` will expand the %username% variable before writing it to the script file:

```
@echo off
del script.txt
echo open FTP.server.com>>script.txt
.
[echo rest of script lines to file]
.
echo lcd "c:\documents and settings\%username%\my documents\FTP">>script.txt
echo echo mput *txt>>script.txt

@ftp -s:script.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `lcd`, a better idea might be to change the working directory in the outer batch file.

```
@echo off

@pushd "c:\documents and settings\%username%\my documents\FTP"

@ftp -s:"%~f0" &GOTO: EOF

open FTP.server.com
user
pass
cd /home/ftp
bin
mput *txt

@pause
```

The only problem with this solution, is that the script itself is no longer in the working directory, and so you need to add a path for that. (Or, put it in the FTP folder ;)

Also, minor pedantry, but this is not actually a correct way to find My documents. In particular, on Vista or Windows 7, User profiles are stored in `C:\Users`. And, it's possible for users to move My Documents (on my computer, My Documents is located in `D:\Mike's Documents`)

However, there doesn't appear to be an environment variable that points directly at My Documents, so you will have to make do with this:

```
"%userprofile%\my documents\FTP"
```

If the people running this script are running XP and haven't moved their My Documents, then this doesn't really matter.

Comment: Yes we're all XP users, for now, trying to convert them to *nix.
Any way %userprofile% works, but it only worked once.
when I run my script again it doesn't work cmd screen just blinks. and
nothing happens..:(

Answer (score 0):

I believe i found a better way, although it's a bit more code.

`set "rootdir=%userprofile%\my documents"`

`set "destdir=c:\`
`for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /b /s "%rootdir%*.txt"') do copy "%%~a" "%destdir%"`

And then the usual FTP stuff, including `lcd c:\`

Ive tested this and it works, although I would like to find a simpler way.
I tried using xcopy but for some reason it doesn't work on my system, the cmd screen just hangs.
Also tried just using `copy`, but that gave me "can't find file" errors.

Comment: The problem with that solution is that it leaves a bunch of files scattered in the root of the drive. What you should try is running my script in an already open console, so you can see what the error is.